# Funcion de ajax no ejecuta las sentencias dentro de success

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy trabajando con laravel, tengo el siguiente código en laravel, copiare parte porque los htmls y funciones php como el formulario, son largos:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
 {{ Form::open(['route' => 'doctor.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'role' =>'form', 'id' => 'formdoctor']) }}
 @include('doctor.formulario')
 {{ Form::close() }}
 </div>  <div id="doctorg"></div>

$('#guardardoctor').click(function () {
        var dato = $("#formdoctor").serialize();
        var route = "{{url('')}}/doctor/guardarajax/";

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: route,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: dato,
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#doctorg").html(result);
                    $("#formdoctor")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

Para resumir la configuración de la ruta está bien, el debuguer me marca 200 cuando se ejecuta la funcion ajax que significa que esta enviando y recibiendo correctamente los datos,

la funcion que llama hace esto

```
public function guardarajax()
{
    return 'hola'; 
}
```

y bueno al final si el success no funciona, si lo coloco con function(), no ejecuta nada, el reset si lo coloco fuera de la funcion ajax funciona correctamente, me asegure de hacer distintas pruebas con diferente código, desde mostrar un alert, que haga lo que sea, pero jamas ejecuta algo que este dentro de success y el depurador no miente, el ajax si manda la petición y si recibe una respuesta correcta, ya no tengo más ideas de lo que pueda suceder, #guardardoctor es un input que esta dentro del formulario que carga, que creen que este fallando? espero haberme dejado entender, gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si lo que devuelves es `"hola"`, eso no es un JSON válido. $.ajax no ejecuta la función `success` porque  el JSON.parse que hace internamente falla (has puesto que esperas un JSON de respuesta al definir `dataType: 'json'`)

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @PabloLozano, lo cual es correcto, no se entiende en tu código cómo llamas a `guardarajax()` ¿? Con que la función exista en el servidor, no devolverá nada si no la llamas. Me parece curiosa también la forma en que construyes la URL en la variable `route`

Comment: Hola Pablo Lozano, muchas gracias!! si tenias razon, lo tube en mis narices todo este tiempo, el código final de esa funcion si devolvera un json y para probar lo puse a lo más básico sin fijarme que ya no devolvia un json, graciaaas, A Cedano, como decia al principio estoy utilizando laravel y laravel tiene sus propias funciones para sacar la dirección báse de la variable route que estoy utilizando, ademas enlaza la dirección que utilizo con la funcion con este código especificoparaesafuncion   Route::post('doctor/guardarajax/','DoctorController@guardarajax'); especificamente para esa funcion